# Why do I have to do (k-pivot+left-1) in case of right subarray while finding kth smallest element in an array?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am running this script to find kth smallest element by using modified Quick Sort Algorithm. Ignore the comments they might be wrong.

I am not able to understand why do I have to (k-pivot+left-1) for right subarray. I have some idea the right subarray is shifted by pivot but I am not able to grasp it completely.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class kthMaxMin {

    public static void Swap(int[] A, int id1, int id2){
        int temp = A[id1];
        A[id1] = A[id2];
        A[id2] = temp;
    }

    public static int Partition(int[] A, int left, int right){
        // Returns pivot index 

        int pivot = A[right];
        int i = left; // Last position of smaller element pointer
        for(int j=left;j<=right-1;j++){ // j is loop pointer
            if(A[j]<=pivot){
                Swap(A, i, j); // Put that element in the new position
                i++;
            }
        }
        Swap(A, i, right); // Put pivot where it belongs i.e. middle
        return (i); // Location of pivot
    }

    public static int QuickSortModified(int[] A, int left, int right, int k){
        // Returns kth smallest element
        
        if(k>0 && k<=right-left+1){ // k is within bounds of the array
                int pivot = Partition(A, left, right);
                if(pivot - left == k-1){ // If number of elements in left subarray is equal to k
                    return A[pivot];     // then return pivot as it is kth smallest element
                }
                if(pivot-left > k-1){ // If size of left subarray is greater than k
                    return QuickSortModified(A, left, pivot-1, k); // Search in left subarray more
                }
                return QuickSortModified(A, pivot+1, right, k-pivot+left-1); // Else Search in right subarray
                                                                             // k-pivot because right subarray is shifted by value = pivot?
        }
        return (-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] Arr = new int[10];
        Arr[0] = 99;
        Arr[1] = 9;
        Arr[2] = 56;
        Arr[3] = 78;
        Arr[4] = 12;
        Arr[5] = 18;
        Arr[6] = 76;
        Arr[7] = 19;
        Arr[8] = 12;
        Arr[9] = 5;
        System.out.println("Array: "+Arrays.toString(Arr));
        int k =5;
        int min = QuickSortModified(Arr, 0, Arr.length-1, k);
        System.out.println(k+"th Smallest Element: "+min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why do I have to (k-pivot+left-1) for right subarray

Because the code is checking for pivot-left == k-1. The way the code in the question is implemented allows for finding the kth element of a portion of an array, rather than the entire array.

With an entry | helper function (QuickSelect() in this example code), the code can be simplfied:

```
    public static int QuickSortModified(int[] A, int left, int right, int k){
        int pivot = Partition(A, left, right);
        if(pivot == k)                  // if k == pivot
            return A[pivot];
        if(pivot > k)                   // if k is in left partition
            return QuickSortModified(A, left, pivot-1, k);
        else                            // if k is in right partition
            return QuickSortModified(A, pivot+1, right, k);
    }

    public static int QuickSelect(int[] A, int left, int right, int k){
        k = k-1;
        if(k < left || k > right)
            return -1;
        return QuickSortModified(A, left, right, k+left);
    }

// ...
// calling example
// ...
        int left = 2;           // normally left  = 0
        int right = 8;          // normally right = Arr.length-1
        int k = 4;
        int min = QuickSelect(Arr, left, right, k);
```